# Ruby on Rails produces 500 internal-server-error in test environment, but log doesn´t show the error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

A certain page in my rails application runs fine in devolopment environment, fails with a 500 internal server error when it is accessed in test environment.

But there is nothing about this error in the log file:

```
Rendered controller/action.html.erb within layouts/application (55.7ms)
Completed   in 230ms
```

Note that the status information in the "completed" line is missing (usually it looks like `Completed 200 OK in 207ms`).

How can I find out what is causing this error, when it is not logged properly?

Answer (score 0):

try to use something like

```
 puts response.to_yaml
```

after http request in test.